# What input class does System.in belongs to and why?

Tags: java, inheritance, io

The code

```
import java.io.*;

class ioTest1{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println(System.in.getClass());
   }
}
```

returns that `System.in` belongs to the `BufferedInputStream` class. Why is that?

Since class `System` defines `System.in` to be `InputStream`, I can see how the result isn't impossible. But why can't the previous code return another class inherited from `InputStream`,like for example `DataInputStream`?

Comment: It could return something else extending the `InputStream` class, if the person who wrote the class had decided to choose another implementation.

Comment: `BufferedInputStream` is a subclass of `InputStream`. `getClass()` _could_ return any subclass of `InputStream`, but the reason it returns `BufferedInputStream` is because that's just how it's implemented -- that is, somewhere, you'd find a line which approximately states `System.in = new BufferedInputStream()` (and not some other kind of stream). Are you asking for the reasons why the developers chose this type of stream?

Comment: If it's a matter of implementation on behalf of the developers then that answers my question. But I am trying to understand how I/O works in Java and I thought it was strange to have such a specified class instantiating the general standard input stream...

Comment: @ThemistoklisHaris Since `InputStream` is abstract, it'll have to be one of the subclasses. `BufferedInputStream` is quite a suitable and obvious choice.

Comment: @Kayaman why in particular is `BufferedInputStream` the better choice over the other flavors of `InputStream`? (That would make a great answer to this question ;) )

Comment: I guess this little comment in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) could give us a little hint. `optimize input and output by reducing the number of calls to the native API.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained in the comments, there's nothing that would have prevented `System.in` from being `DataInputStream`, but given that `BufferedInputStream` is a no-frills `InputStream` that includes buffering of data (always a good idea), it makes more sense to give the most generic type possible.

Developers can then wrap the buffered stream with for example a `DataInputStream` if the program is fed piped binary data, or an `InputStreamReader` if the program is receiving text data from the user.

`System.in` is a `BufferedInputStream` because it doesn't need to be anything else.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that it is just how it's implemented.

If you look at the source code of java.lang.System class, you will see that System.in is set [natively](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c) (See Java_java_lang_System_setIn0).

Different JVM implementers may use any InputStream implementation they prefer. In your case `BufferedInputStream` is used, presumably, for its efficiency.