# What does system.in contain?

Tags: java, class, io, reference

I'm trying to improve my understanding of IO. So as I understand it, 'in' is a member variable of the System class.

I believe it's a reference variable due to its type being 'InputStream' as mentioned at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

However, 'InputStream' is an abstract class so it cannot be instantiated.

I've done some testing and came to conclusion that although you cannot instantiate an abstract class, you can create a reference variable of an abstract class type.  So my first question is there a purpose for this, if not, why is it allowed?

```
Example: 

abstract class Someclass {
;
}

Someclass variable; // A field member of some another class. What purpose could it serve?
```

So here comes my second batch of related questions. What does system.in variable contain (or references) ? It surely is not

InputStream in = new InputStream();

because it's an abstract class. Does this mean it has an instance of some child subclass? If so, which one? Is there a way to view the 'body' of field popular variables and methods online?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** Duplicate suggestions did not resolve the issue. The only thing I got a grasp of is that InputStream maybe instantiated with the BufferedStream class.

Questions below still stand:

1.) Is there a way to view the 'body' of field popular variables and methods online? 
2.) Why is it allowed to make a reference of abstract class and what's the purpose of it?

3.) And the new question that rose as a sequence of the suggestions - why is it `InputStream in = new BufferedStream()` instead of `BufferedStream in = new BufferedStream()`

Comment: `System.in` references the implementation of `InputStream` which takes input from the outside world, typically from the keyboard, but input can be piped in through other means (commonly known as stdin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of abstract classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288467/what-is-the-purpose-of-abstract-classes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What input class does System.in belongs to and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051872/what-input-class-does-system-in-belongs-to-and-why)

Answer (score 1):

For the question

> 3.) And the new question that rose as a sequence of the suggestions - why is it InputStream in = new BufferedStream() instead of
>   BufferedStream in = new BufferedStream()

Read about dependency injection.

For

> 2.) Why is it allowed to make a reference of abstract class and what's the purpose of it?

All I can say from my knowledge is: by definition, we CANNOT create a **NEW** instance of the abstract class, but we can use an existing one. As it could still have the Data Member and Data Variable. And since those data members **MAY NOT BE static**, we would need a name reference to access it.

your question 1 is unclear. But if want to see the source code from a .class file, read about decompiler. And Java is shipped with it.

Answer (score 0):

System.in is an InputStream which is typically connected to keyboard input of console programs. System.in is not used as often since data is commonly passed to a command line Java application via command line arguments, or configuration files. In applications with GUI the input to the application is given via the GUI. This is a separate input mechanism from Java IO. System itself is a public final class in the java.lang package that contains several methods for input, output, and error outputting.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not what it does, its role or popularity, but rather how it's implemented + a few additional questions about reference variables below the EDIT